# How to create Meteor OAuth Login Buttons similar to those in Accounts-UI?

Tags: oauth, meteor, user-accounts

Currently I use the [Meteor-Accounts-UI-Bootstrap-3-Blaze package](https://github.com/mangasocial/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3) in my navigation bar, which is pretty much the Accounts-UI package with bootstrap over it.

I want to have a separate sign up form for the splash screen, instead of just having it in the navigation bar (similar to what Facebook and Twitter do on their splash screens).

> Is there any simple way to take essentially what is in the Accounts-UI
>   package dropdown and display it on the splash screen?

**OR**

> Is there any simple way to make a quick OAuth login button for the
>   splash screen?

*Thanks*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to make a custom button with id googleLoginButton for the Google OAuth login flow for example you would do

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'click #googleLoginButton': function() {
    Meteor.loginWithGoogle();
  }
});
```

if you want to add scopes

```
Meteor.loginWithGoogle({ requestPermissions: ['email', 'profile'] });
```

Note: you will still need to do the initial configuration where you add the clientId and clientSecret.

What I do is have a helper to check if the service is configured and if not display {{> loginButtons}}

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  google_configured: function() {
    return ServiceConfiguration.configurations.findOne({service: 'google'});
  }
});
```

You could use that ServiceConfiguration collection to query all OAuth services you have configured and make custom login buttons for them all

Comment: I think they may have updated what the ServiceConfiguration is called for the client. I see the meteor_accounts_loginServiceConfiguration on the server, but I can't seem to find the client side collection just to check which are enabled. Any ideas? Thanks for the help